# ng-repeat array in array filtering by property of parent with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to select an array in array by property of the parent. I don't know the index (in this case 1), but I know the id. Can I do it? This is my working example with index, I want same results by id (43).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="p in people[1].rooms" ng-bind="p"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.people = [
    {
        id: 25,
        nick: 'Joker',
        rooms: ['room1', 'room2']
    },
    {
        id: 43,
        nick: 'King',
        rooms: ['room3', 'room4']
    },
    {
        id: 78,
        nick: 'Queen',
        rooms: ['room5', 'room6']
    }
 ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate get rooms for particular user by its id using strict filter on `people` array. Its obvious that you are going to a single record as its `id` based search.

**Code**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="p in filteredPeople = (people | filter: {id: l.id })[0].rooms">
       {{p}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And how can I get the rooms? In "p" I have the people filtered, and in p.rooms I have the array of rooms

Answer (score 2):

This is one option:

```
<ul ng-repeat="p in people | filter: { id: 45 }">
    <li ng-repeat="room in p.rooms" ng-bind="room"></li>
</ul>
```